# Crashing with error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

Using Crashlytics, I see that a small subset of my users are crashing with the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`, on the following line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

I have been unable to reproduce the crash, but is there some way I can safeguard the line or modify it to prevent future crashes? It's designed to completely remove any views/subviews on the screen.

Please let me know if more information is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution

```
if ( [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate != nil) {
     for (UIView *subView in [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.subviews) {
         if ([subView respondsToSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]) {
            [subView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: This should work, though I'll report back if it doesn't once the update goes live!

Comment: OK awesome try and let me know